# CKEditor removes custom <span> with a class

Tags: jquery, html, forms, tags, ckeditor

I have a form on my website where admin can edit the contract which is shown on the registration form. there are few fields in a form which are dynamic meaning on the first page of registration form there is first name, last name of the person who is registering. I want to get his names and replace with `template_field_name` as defined in contract.
Here is a sample of what i am trying to do

```html
<p>contactor: <span class="template_name">template_name</span></p>
```

later when the page renders on registration form i will look for `template_name` class and replace the text with jquery to the value i am getting from first name and last name field from the first page of registration form. but when admin make some changes later to contract it just eliminate the `span` tag with class name

```html
<p>contactor:template_name</p>
```

and outputs the `template_name` as above. I am tired to this issue and tried so many times to solve this.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your problem in Advanced Content Filtering (ACF) of CKEditor.

Try to set configuration option to allow everything:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

See if it's working for you. If it is, replace `config.allowedContent` with:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'span(template_name)';
```

which will allow the class `template_name` for the `span` tag.

More information about ACF here - https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_acf

To add multiply allowed classes you can specify them separated by comma:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'span(template_name,another_class,one_more_class)';
```

Or you can allow every class for span tag, like this:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'span(*)';
```

If fields represent by different tags - you need separate them by space

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'span(template_name) p(another_template_name)';
```

Comment: how do i add multiple fields in extraallowedcontent? i have 4 fields in total firstname, lastname, email, and address.

Comment: @JahanAhmedAbbasi I added more examples for multiple fields to answer. Please, check